# Vue Js v-btn-toggle class to select specific index with Mandatory Prop

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am new to VueJs , I am working on array of Elements, the requirement is by default we need to select the 3rd array position, Upon clicking Specific index to be selected.

For this i am using mandatory prop but by default it is selected to array position 1. i am using the toggle_exclusive class i can reach the o/p but after selecting Specific index complete row is selecting.

Please Help me to sort out this.

thanks.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  and update your question accordingly.

Comment: `Upon clicking Specific index to be selected` sounds like either we should use `data` to store what is selected, or $emit what was clicked, where the prop gets updated.